# Odd behaviour with a while loop (not as expected!)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I've written a short program which essentially chooses 3 objects from 3 lists, indexes the choices and then *should* never be able to make the same choices again. It's very close, only issue is instead of never choosing the sequence again, it *always* chooses the same sequence?

```
trial_index = 0 
trials = [None] 

digits = ['0', '1','2','3'] 
word = [ "word1", "word2"]
images = [image1, image2, image3] 

digit_index = random.randint(0,3) 
word_index = random.randint(0,1)
image_index = random.randint(0,2) 

trials[trial_index] = digit_index + word_index + image_index

trial_index+=1 

selected_trial = " " 
selected_trial = trials

# Up until this point behaviour functions as expected I think... 

# This doesn't work, I assumed that what would occur is that as long as this evaluated to TRUE it would run this code forcing it to choose a new sequence? 

while selected_trial in trials: 

    digit_index = random.randint(0,3)
    word_index = random.randint(0,1)
    image_index = random.randint(0,13)
    selected_trial = digit_index + word_index + image_index 
    trials[trial_index] = selected_trial
    trial_index += 1
```

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - it can help to find out where is the problem.

Comment: Directly before your `while` loop, you assign the list `trials` to your `selected_trial` variable. So unless your list contains itself as an element, the loop will never run.

Comment: I wonder how this would even work without throwing an error. `trial_index` is 0 at first, filling the first entry of `trials` (which is `None` at first). Then `trial_index` becomes 1 and then the line of code `trials[trial_index]` will fail, because `trials` is of length 1.

Comment: better use `random.shuffle` to create list with items in random order and then you can get first element, next time second element, etc - and you don't need to remeber indexes. You can even use `for` and `zip()` to create groups.

Comment: You should check your example. There is any `imageX` variable and the index for images is in `range(0,3)` not `range(0,13)`. You might find interesting read [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: @ChristianKönig, good spot, alright so i've [0]'d selected_trial = trials[0], trials = [0] &  trials[trial_index] = selected_trial[0] 

Apart from now I get the error... 

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in trials[trial_index] = selected_trial[0]

Comment: @furas, indeed, random.shuffle does not work for this particular problem though

Comment: Yes, before commend I though that `digit` can't repeat in any group, after my commend I understood that it can repeat in other groups but groups can't repeat. So I use `random.choice` in asnwer to make it simpler.

Comment: why do you add indexes ? it gives single number. Shouldn't you concatenate items or keep indexes as tuple or list ( `(digit_index, word_index, image_index)` ?

Comment: you do `selected_trials = trials` so you later have `while trials in trials`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `random.choice` I made it simpler - and now it works correctly.

```
import random

digits = ['0', '1','2','3'] 
word   = ['word1', 'word2']
images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3'] 

trials = []

d = random.choice(digits)
w = random.choice(word)
i = random.choice(images)

trials.append( (d,w,i) )

while (d,w,i) in trials:
    d = random.choice(digits)
    w = random.choice(word)
    i = random.choice(images)

trials.append( (d,w,i) )

print(trials)
```

---

**EDIT:** this works with indexes

```
import random

trials = [] 
trial_index = 0 

digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3'] 
word   = [ "word1", "word2"]
images = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3'] 

digit_index = random.randint(0, 3) 
word_index  = random.randint(0, 1)
image_index = random.randint(0, 2) 

selected_trial = (digit_index, word_index, image_index)

trials.append( selected_trial )
trial_index += 1 
#trial_index = len(trials)

while selected_trial in trials: 

    digit_index = random.randint(0, 3)
    word_index  = random.randint(0, 1)
    image_index = random.randint(0, 2)
    selected_trial = (digit_index, word_index, image_index)

trials.append( selected_trial )
trial_index += 1
#trial_index = len(trials)

print( trials )
```

Comment: Very nice Furas, thankyou unfortunately I had already had something similar to this solution but it breaks the code further downstream, hence the indexing ;-)

Comment: I made version with indexes.

Comment: Aha! Brilliant, thankyou very much furas, you're a gent, did not know .append allowed you to index blank arrays either, the more you know!